# Tensorflow: cross-validation and test error graph

Tags: tensorflow, cross-validation

With boosting and random forests, I used early stopping and plotted the train AND test error while training in order to get a feeling when the model is overfitting.

a) in tensorflow (multilayer perceptron), I can plot the training error while training (cost/epoch graph), but how can I get the test error graph while training?

b) is there a built-in cross-validation function in tensorflow (eg 5-fold cv)? If not, what is the most efficient way to do cv with tensorflow?